# SetCustomClaims is not being set for the first TimeAttempt in firebase-admin

Tags: firebase, next.js, firebase-admin

Basically, the problem is in the **firebase auth admin** where I am doing with Next.js Api,
there is problem when newly user sign in with google provider so, the **setCustomUserClaims** is not embedded for the first in the JWT Token, but when same user attempt the 2nd time then its embedded, I don't know what is problem why is not being set for the first time also, and also I try to **createCustomToken** then its embedded **customerClaims** but it given me an error,

```
FirebaseAuthError: The provided ID token is not a valid Firebase ID token.
```

but I want to set the customerClaims is being set for the default token, not in the customToken, Is there anyway for proper doing it ? Please help :((

this is my Next.js Backend where I am doing this

```
const authorization = req.headers["authorization"];

  const expiresIn = 10800000;


  if (authorization?.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
    const idToken = authorization.split("Bearer ")[1];


    try {
      const decodeToken = await auth().verifyIdToken(idToken);

      const entries = await firestore().collection('Users').doc(decodeToken.uid).get();

      const profile = entries.data();

      console.log("profileprofile", profile);


      if (profile && profile.user_type) {

        const navBar = await firestore().collection('Navbars').doc(profile?.user_type).get();

        const navBarData = navBar.data();

        console.log("navBarDatanavBarData", navBarData);


        if (navBarData) {

          const customClaims = {
            user_type: profile.user_type,
            Navbar: navBarData
          };


          try {

            await auth().setCustomUserClaims(decodeToken.uid, customClaims);

            const updatedToken = await auth().createCustomToken(decodeToken.uid, customClaims);


            const user = await auth().getUser(decodeToken.uid);

            console.log("useruser", user);

            if (decodeToken) {

              const sessionCookie = await auth().createSessionCookie(idToken, {
                expiresIn,
              });

              const options: any = {
                name: "session",
                value: sessionCookie,
                maxAge: expiresIn,
                httpOnly: true,
                secure: true
              }

              setCookie(options.name, options.value, { req, res, maxAge: options.maxAge });

              res.status(200).json({});

            }
          }
          catch (err) {
            console.log("errerr", err);
          }


        }


      }

    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error verifying ID token:', error);
    }
  }
  else {
    res.status(401).json({ error: 'Unauthorized' }); // Handle unauthorized request
  }
```